# Python Child/Parent classes, Child Class Returning String Twice?

Tags: python, string, parent-child

Easy question and probably very obvious to one of you, but Im unsure of why this happends. So here are the three python files Ive made.

**Main Char class:**

```
class Character():
    """
    This is the main parents class for creation of
    characters, be they player, NPC or monsters they
    shall all share common traits
    """

    def __init__(self, name, health, defense):
        """Constructor for Character"""
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense
```

**Player class:**

```
from character import *

class Player(Character):
    """
    The player class is where heros are made
    They inherit common traits from the Character class
    """

    def __init__(self, name, health, defense, str, int):
        Character.__init__(self, name, health, defense)
        self.str = str
        self.int = int
```

**Init:**

```
from Letsago.player import Player


hero = Player("Billy", 200, 10, 10, 2)    
print hero.name
```

**This results in:**

```
Billy
Billy
```

Why is it being returned twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have put your example in a file called `test.py`:

```
class Character():
    """
    This is the main parents class for creation of
    characters, be they player, NPC or monsters they
    shall all share common traits
    """

    def __init__(self, name, health, defense):
        """Constructor for Character"""
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.defense = defense


class Player(Character):
    """
    The player class is where heros are made
    They inherit common traits from the Character class
    """

    def __init__(self, name, health, defense, str, int):
        Character.__init__(self, name, health, defense)
        self.str = str
        self.int = int


hero = Player("Billy", 200, 10, 10, 2)
print hero.name
```

and executed the following (python 2.7 on ubuntu 13.04):

```
python test.py
```

and got the following in the console

```
Billy
```

Try to isolate the example like I did in one single file and execute it (outside of an interactive shell). Also check your modules and check your `from character import *`. Be sure that you are importing the correct `Player` class

Comment: I changed `from Letsago.player import Player` to `from player import *` and its returning `Billy` once how it should. Why does it do it twice the first way? I checked and it is importing the right file I wonder? Well regardless it works and thanks for the tip. Im just unsure why it would do that

Comment: It looks like you have the Player class duplicated in your modules:  `Letsago.player.Player` and `character.Player`